# Codeigniter with Wordpress routing

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I needed to insert data from app database to the wordpress blog. So I came up with the following setup, where I used CodeIgniter as a theme to the Wordpress.

```
localhost
 -myProject(Wordpress)
  -wp-content
   -themes
    -myTheme(CodeIgniter)
     -application
      -modules
       -forums
        -controllers
         -Forums.php
        -views
         -forums_view.php
```

Now if we call `Forums` then the Forums.php controller's `index` function catches the call, but if we call `Forums/forum/something` then the Forums.php controller's `forum` function does not catch the call.

This is all the routings I tried but nothing worked, every time whenever there is one or more levels to the uri the page lands up on error_404 page.

```
$route['(?i)Forums/forum/(:any)'] = 'Forums/forum/$1';
$route['(?i)forums/forum/(:any)'] = 'forums/forum/$1';
$route['(?i)forums/forum/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'forums/forum/$1';
$route['(?i)forums/forum/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'forums/forum/$1';
$route['(?i)forums/forum/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'forums/forum/$1';
```

Comment: what does `(?)` mean? and what is your base_url? I think you do not need routing for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of this setup, but you might try reversing the order. Routes are processed in the order listed. So it could be that your script never gets to the intended routing rules.

Comment: You are quite correct. Longest routes (left side) should be before most general routes (shortest ones).